# Error when using two models in index page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I generated a simple MVC5 application (code first with scaffold for the views) and it generates for me the views for every action index, create, edit etc

I want to copy the code from the **create view  to the index view** but in the index the model is declared like below :

```
@model IEnumerable<Ro01.Models.Ro>
```

and when I copy it to the view and run it I get an error. I can use only one model, how should I overcome this?

since the code of the create (razor code) having errors...

```
@model Role.Models.Ro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a ViewModel. Create a ViewModels folder in your project and add a class like this:

```
public class FooViewModel
{

public IEnumerable<Ro01.Models.Ro> Model1 {get;set;}

public FooClass Model2 {get;set;}

}
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
FooViewModel model = new FooModel();
model.Model1 = new Ro01.Models.Ro();
mode.Model2 = new FooClass();

return View(model);
}
```

and then use it your View like this:

```
   @model Ro01.ViewModels.FooViewModel


@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Model1.SomeProperty)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Model2.SomeProperty)
```

Comment: Can you please guide me how to create the view model ?this is just regular model?And how should I refer to the fields from the model 1 and model 2?

Comment: create a folder in project name ViewModels and in that add new class